# Изменение цвета фона (CardBackgroundColor) при клике на CardView

Tags: android, recyclerview, cardview

Есть `RecyclerView`, в нем элементы представляют из себя `CardView` с элементами.
Привязал `selector` к `CardView`, но при клике не меняется цвет фона.
У `CardView` не работает `selector`? Сделал его в `/color` вроде все верно

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать setOnTouchListener

Comment: К сожалению косяк с прокруткой

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужен не конкретный цвет, а подойдет стандартный Ripple-эффект, то можете в `xml` для `CardView` использовать `android:foreground="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`